# Python : TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < float(),

Tags: apache-spark, typeerror

I have a large dataframe  in pyspark with one column called distance_range looks like this:

```
    +---------------------+
    |distance_range|
    +---------------------+
    |             6-10 mil|
    |              2-4 mil|
    |            10-15 mil|
    |            20-30 mil|
    |            15-20 mil|
    |              4-6 mil|
    |             6-10 mil|
    |            0.5-2 mil|
    |              2-4 mil|
    |              2-4 mil|
    |              4-6 mil|
    |            30-40 mil|
```

while I want to see the distinct values of this columns and further to pivot with this col.

```
    df.select('distance_range').distinct().show()
```

it always return error:

```
     Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1884.showString.
     TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < float()
```

this column is string type and no null value

this column was generated by

```
     def dist_range(distance):
         elif 0.5 <= distance <2:
                return '0.5-2 mil'
         elif  2 <= distance <4:
                return '2-4 mil'
                .
                .
                .
         elif 20 <= distance  <30:
               return '20-30 mil'
         else 30 <= distance  <40:
              return '30-40 mil'

    udf_distance_range = udf(dist_range, StringType())

    df = original_df.withColumn("distance_range", udf_distance_range("home_store_dist"))
```

Comment: did you do anything before like a sort or orderby?

Comment: Without distinct(), it will return all the values of distance_range, but if I want to check the distinct  values, it will return this error. I did not do sort r orderby  for this  distinct() method.

Comment: My initial intention is to pivot on this distance_range column after group by the other columns, but it returned these error too. Then I went back to to check distinct value of distance_range  by  df.select('distance_range').distinct().show(), it also returns this error.